# Tomcat don't run sakai

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, sakai

I'm installing [sakai](https://github.com/sakaiproject/sakai), I got "BUILD SUCCESS" but when run tomcat this no work, so look like java execution error.

My environment:

- Sakai (from github)
- Apache Maven 3.0.5

  Maven home: /usr/share/maven
  Java version: 1.8.0_05, vendor: Oracle Corporation
  Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_05/jre Default locale: es_CO,
  platform encoding: UTF-8 OS name: "linux", version: "3.11-2-amd64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
- Tomcat 8.0.21
- Java

  java version "1.8.0_05"
  Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_05-b13)
  Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.5-b02, mixed mode)

When run tomcat I get this:

```
rizotas@g4:~/Proyectos/sakai/apache-tomcat-8.0.21/bin$ ./startup.sh && tail -f ../logs/catalina.out 
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /home/rizotas/Proyectos/sakai/apache-tomcat-8.0.21
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /home/rizotas/Proyectos/sakai/apache-tomcat-8.0.21
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /home/rizotas/Proyectos/sakai/apache-tomcat-8.0.21/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr
Using CLASSPATH:       /home/rizotas/Proyectos/sakai/apache-tomcat-8.0.21/bin/bootstrap.jar:/home/rizotas/Proyectos/sakai/apache-tomcat-8.0.21/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Tomcat started.
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)

04-May-2015 18:19:17.807 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
04-May-2015 18:19:17.807 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
04-May-2015 18:19:17.807 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stopInternal Parando servicio Catalina
04-May-2015 18:19:17.953 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
04-May-2015 18:19:17.953 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
04-May-2015 18:19:17.954 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
04-May-2015 18:19:17.954 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=320m; support was removed in 8.0
04-May-2015 18:20:08.922 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory.validateFile Problem with directory [/home/rizotas/Proyectos/sakai/apache-tomcat-8.0.21/server/classes/,/home/rizotas/Proyectos/sakai/apache-tomcat-8.0.21/server/lib], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
04-May-2015 18:20:09.018 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory.validateFile Problem with directory [/home/rizotas/Proyectos/sakai/apache-tomcat-8.0.21/shared/classes/,/home/rizotas/Proyectos/sakai/apache-tomcat-8.0.21/shared/lib], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
04-May-2015 18:20:10.648 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.21
04-May-2015 18:20:10.649 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Mar 23 2015 14:11:21 UTC
04-May-2015 18:20:10.649 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.0.21.0
04-May-2015 18:20:10.649 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
04-May-2015 18:20:10.649 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            3.11-2-amd64
04-May-2015 18:20:10.649 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
04-May-2015 18:20:10.650 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_05/jre
04-May-2015 18:20:10.650 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_05-b13
04-May-2015 18:20:10.650 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
04-May-2015 18:20:10.650 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /home/rizotas/Proyectos/sakai/apache-tomcat-8.0.21
04-May-2015 18:20:10.650 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /home/rizotas/Proyectos/sakai/apache-tomcat-8.0.21
04-May-2015 18:20:10.651 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/home/rizotas/Proyectos/sakai/apache-tomcat-8.0.21/conf/logging.properties
04-May-2015 18:20:10.651 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
04-May-2015 18:20:10.651 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xmx1028m
04-May-2015 18:20:10.651 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -XX:MaxPermSize=320m
04-May-2015 18:20:10.651 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dorg.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.STRICT_QUOTE_ESCAPING=false
04-May-2015 18:20:10.652 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.awt.headless=true
04-May-2015 18:20:10.652 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
04-May-2015 18:20:10.652 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dsun.lang.ClassLoader.allowArraySyntax=true
04-May-2015 18:20:10.652 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/home/rizotas/Proyectos/sakai/apache-tomcat-8.0.21/endorsed
04-May-2015 18:20:10.652 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/home/rizotas/Proyectos/sakai/apache-tomcat-8.0.21
04-May-2015 18:20:10.652 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/home/rizotas/Proyectos/sakai/apache-tomcat-8.0.21
04-May-2015 18:20:10.653 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/rizotas/Proyectos/sakai/apache-tomcat-8.0.21/temp
04-May-2015 18:20:10.653 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent La biblioteca nativa de Apache Tomcat basada en ARP que permite un rendimiento óptimo en entornos de desarrollo no ha sido hallada en java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
04-May-2015 18:20:11.286 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
04-May-2015 18:20:11.323 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
04-May-2015 18:20:11.342 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
04-May-2015 18:20:11.344 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
04-May-2015 18:20:11.344 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 1773 ms
04-May-2015 18:20:11.481 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Arrancando servicio Catalina
04-May-2015 18:20:11.481 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.21
04-May-2015 18:20:11.570 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Despliegue del archivo /home/rizotas/Proyectos/sakai/apache-tomcat-8.0.21/webapps/sakai-sections-tool.war de la aplicación web
04-May-2015 18:20:13.652 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/sakai-sections-tool]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:940)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1738)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/springframework/context/ApplicationContext;
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2570)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1903)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationFilterAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:64)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:334)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:774)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5065)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1305)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1157)
    ... 24 more

04-May-2015 18:20:13.654 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Error durante el despliegue del archivo /home/rizotas/Proyectos/sakai/apache-tomcat-8.0.21/webapps/sakai-sections-tool.war de la aplicación web
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/sakai-sections-tool]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:940)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1738)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

04-May-2015 18:20:13.671 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive /home/rizotas/Proyectos/sakai/apache-tomcat-8.0.21/webapps/sakai-sections-tool.war has finished in 2.085 ms
04-May-2015 18:20:13.703 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Despliegue del archivo /home/rizotas/Proyectos/sakai/apache-tomcat-8.0.21/webapps/sakai-site-manage-group-section-role-helper.war de la aplicación web
04-May-2015 18:20:14.567 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars Al menos un JAR, que se ha explorado buscando TLDs, aún no contenía TLDs. Activar historial de depuración para este historiador para una completa lista de los JARs que fueron explorados y de los que nos se halló TLDs. Saltarse JARs no necesarios durante la exploración puede dar lugar a una mejora de tiempo significativa en el arranque y compilación de JSP .
04-May-2015 18:20:14.653 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Error listenerStart
^C
```

Thanks so much for your help.

Saludos :)

Comment: Have you modified your conf/catalina.properties file per Sakai recommendations?

Comment: Try all of the steps here https://confluence.sakaiproject.org/display/BOOT/Install+Tomcat+7 including modifying catalina.properties and using Tomcat 7 for Sakai 10 and Tomcat 8 for Sakai 11 (trunk).

Answer (score -1):

your tomcat is 8, I see  that they mention tomcat 7 in their installation steps. for your error you have to check your spring version is it tested with tomcat 8 or no, i think spring v 4 is support tomcat 8.